# iOS App crashes on phone, works flawlessly in iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, debugging, device

What is the best way to debug that? It just "crashes" on the phone, no message, nothing. Simulator is doing just fine. Happens on only one of the UIViewController's, not sure why...

Comment: view the device in organizer - you can view the logs from there.

Comment: or debug it with the device attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach the debugger when running on the device, see if it is produced that case. Otherwise, check the device logs in the organizer. Logs are left on the device when the app crashes. They can be symbolicated to find out this information.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to add NSZombieEnabled and set it to YES in your enviornment, you can set this in Project->Edit active executable->(go to Agruments tab) and add to Variables to be set in enviornment, so you can see(if you are lucky) where is the problem. Remember to remove it before the upload of your app on the store.

You could also download [this](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/console/id317676250) app from the store.

Comment: Also only use Zombies in the simulator, they never release memory.  I also like to enable the other memory management options (Scribble, Guard Edges, Guard Malloc and Log Exceptions in the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone out of your way to completely clean out prior installations of your app when installing the new version?  Inconsistencies between remnants of the old version installed on the real device and the new install can lead to this situation.